# rmi server throws AccessControlException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rmi

I am trying to build a client-server relationship with a tutorial from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html). My server class is in the engine package in my path: /home/rozerin/IdeaProjects/computetest/src/main/java/engine and client and the interface packages are also in ~/main/java package. 
Like suggested in previous questions about this problem, I ended my directory for permission in policy file with a "/", but it didn't work. Right now, my policy file is in engine folder. 
I am using Intellij Idea for compilation, yet i didn't use the IDE since i am trying to build the server from command line in ubuntu. I don't know what is wrong and I am very stuck at that point.

My parameters for command line is like following;

> java -cp /home/rozerin/IdeaProjects/computetest/src/main/java:/home/rozerin/Public/public_html/classes/compute.jar -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=http://mycomputer/home/rozerin/IdeaProjects/computetest/src/main/java/compute.jar -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=mycomputer.example.com -Djava.security.policy=server.policy engine/ComputeEngine

My client class is like following;

```
package client;

/**
 * Created by rozerin on 08.03.2016.
 */
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import compute.Compute;

public class ComputePi {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
    try {
        String name = "Compute";
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(args[0]);
        Compute comp = (Compute) registry.lookup(name);
        Pi task = new Pi(Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        BigDecimal pi = comp.executeTask(task);
        System.out.println(pi);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ComputePi exception:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

My server class is like following;

```
package engine;

/**
 * Created by rozerin on 08.03.2016.
 */
 import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import compute.Compute;
import compute.Task;

public class ComputeEngine implements Compute {

    public ComputeEngine() {
    super();
    }

    public <T> T executeTask(Task<T> t) {
    return t.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
      try {
        String name = "Compute";
        Compute engine = new ComputeEngine();
        Compute stub =
                (Compute) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        registry.rebind(name, stub);
        System.out.println("ComputeEngine bound");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ComputeEngine exception:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

My policy file is

> grant codeBase "file:/home/rozerin/IdeaProjects/computetest/src/main/java/"{
>       permission java.security.AllPermission;
>   };

Stack trace is;

> ComputeEngine exception:
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:474)
>       at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:685)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:574)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:208)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
>       at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
>       at engine.ComputeEngine.main(ComputeEngine.java:33)

"at engine.ComputeEngine.main(ComputeEngine.java:33)" is where it uses **rebind** method of the server class.

The interfaces are in the website I shared, I don't want to make this place too crowdy. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you use in security policy file `grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    };`

Comment: It is the same error again. It seems it can't find the policy file. What do you think?

Comment: If your 'server won't compile', how exactly did you manage to run it and get an exception?

Comment: @EJP I am using command line

Comment: That is not an answer to my question. You can't execute code that doesn't compile. So either you didn't get this exception or your title is wrong.

Comment: That title is more concrete now. Thanks.

Comment: It is both 'more concrete' and not a contradiction of your actual post. You still don't seem to understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For server side and for client side both should use this:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "path_to_your_Security_policy_file_located_in_file_system");
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
```

Security policy file should contain

```
 grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    };
```

I think this may help you out.

Comment: Is file path supposed to be written like this? 
public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }
        try {
            System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "/home/rozerin/IdeaProjects/computetest/src/main/java/engine/server.policy");
            
            String name = "Compute";
            Compute engine = new ComputeEngine();
     and etc..

Comment: In my case I used for security policy file path `"C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\RmiServerSide\\src\\com\\test\\server\\Security.policy"`

Comment: Mine is same as yours but in ubuntu file system. I tried but again it didn't work. Do you think there can be something wrong  with my server class?

Comment: Check your folder permission.also can you can try to put your policy file inside home folder and test it if that work.

Comment: You can follow the basic here. http://ataurrahmanmunna.blogspot.com/2015/12/java-rmi-remote-method-invocation.html

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Re your blog, the impl class does not need to be distributed to the client.

Comment: @EJP, yes i know. this is for a very basic tutorial just to show how rmi works. :)

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I totally did the same way as your tutorial suggests. There seems to be something different happening that stops the server to work.

Comment: Can you download the sample project and run it at your side?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fe0t4aOZdfaVVWRWhIVHM3Z3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you sir. You saved me.

Comment: @sk001 my pleasure. :)